# How can I make a reactive array from a Meteor collection?

Tags: meteor

I want to take a list of item names from a collection as a simple array to use for things like autocompleting user input and checking for duplicates. I would like this list to be reactive so that changes in the data will be reflected in the array. I have tried the following based on the Meteor documentation:

```
    setReactiveArray = (objName, Collection, field) ->
        update = ->
          context = new Meteor.deps.Context()
          context.on_invalidate update
          context.run -> 
            list = Collection.find({},{field: 1}).fetch()
            myapp[objName] = _(list).pluck field
        update()

    Meteor.startup ->
        if not app.items?
            setReactiveArray('items', Items, 'name')

    #set autocomplete using the array
    Template.myForm.set_typeahead =  ->
       Meteor.defer ->
        $('[name="item"]').typeahead {source: app.items}
```

This code seems to work, but it kills my app's load time (takes 5-10 seconds to load on dev/localhost vs. ~1 second without this code). Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edit**: I have updated the code below both because it was fragile, and to put it in context so it's easier to test. I have also added a caution - in most cases, you will want to use @zorlak's or @englandpost's methods (see below).

---

First of all, kudos to @zorlak for digging up my old question that nobody answered. I have since solved this with a couple of [insights gleaned from @David Wihl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635726/406226) and will post my own solution. I will hold off on selecting the correct answer until others have a chance to weigh in.

@zorlak's answer solves the autocomplete issue for a single field, but as stated in the question, I was looking for **an array** that would update reactively, and the autocomplete was just one example of what it would be used for. The advantage of having this array is that it can be used anywhere (not just in template helpers) and that it can be used multiple times in the code without having to re-execute the query (and the `_.pluck()` that reduces the query to an array). In my case, this array ends up in multiple autocomplete fields as well as validation and other places. It's possible that the advantages I'm putting forth are not significant in most Meteor apps (please leave comments), but this seems like an advantage to me.

To make the array reactive, simply build it inside a `Meteor.autorun()` callback - it will re-execute any time the target collection changes (but only then, avoiding repetitive queries). This was the key insight I was looking for. Also, using the `Template.rendered()` callback is cleaner and less of a hack than the `set_typeahead` template helper I used in the question. The code below uses [underscore.js's `_.pluck()`](http://underscorejs.org/#pluck) to extract the array from the collection and uses [Twitter bootstrap's `$.typeahead()`](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) to create the autocomplete.

*Updated code*: I have edited the code so you can try this with a stock `meteor create`d test environment. Your html will need a line `<input id="typeahead" />` in the 'hello' template. `@Items` has the `@` sign to make `Items` available as a global on the console ([Meteor 0.6.0 added file-level variable scoping](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration)). That way you can enter new items in the console, such as `Items.insert({name: "joe"})`, but the `@` is not necessary for the code to work. The other necessary change for standalone use is that the typeahead function now sets the source to a function (`->`) so that it will query `items` when activated instead of being set at rendering, which allows it to take advantage of changes to `items`.

```
@Items = new Meteor.Collection("items")
items = {}

if Meteor.isClient
  Meteor.startup ->
    Meteor.autorun ->
      items = _(Items.find().fetch()).pluck "name"
      console.log items  #first result will be empty - see caution below

  Template.hello.rendered = ->
    $('#typeahead').typeahead {source: -> _(Items.find().fetch()).pluck "name"}
```

**Caution! The array we created is not *itself* a reactive data source.** The reason that the typeahead `source:` needed to be set to a *function* `->` that returned `items` is that when Meteor first starts, the code runs before Minimongo has gotten its data from the server, and `items` is set to an empty array. Minimongo then receives its data, and `items` is updated You can see this process if you run the above code with the console open: `console.log items` will log twice if you have any data stored.

`Template.x.rendered()` calls don't don't set a reactivity context and so won't retrigger due to changes in reactive elements (to check this, pause your code in the debugger and examine `Deps.currentComputation` -- if it's `null`, you are not in a reactive context and changes to reactive elements will be ignored). But you might be surprised to learn that your templates and helpers will also not react to `items` changing -- a template using `#each` to iterate over `items` will render empty and never rerender. You could make it act as a reactive source (the simplest way being to store the result with `Session.set()`, or [you can do it yourself](http://www.eventedmind.com/posts/meteor-build-a-reactive-data-source)), but unless you are doing a very expensive calculation that should be run as seldom as possible, you are better off using @zorlak's or @englandpost's methods. It may seem expensive to have your app querying the database repetitively, but Minimongo is caching the data locally, avoiding the network, so it will be quite fast. Thus in most situations, it's better just to use

```
  Template.hello.rendered = ->
    $('#typeahead').typeahead {source: -> _(Items.find().fetch()).pluck "name"}
```

unless you find that your app is really bogging down.

Comment: Ah, yeah this is a better answer than mine for two reasons: 1) you actually wanted the array to update reactively, but NOT to re-run its enclosing function, since the typeahead only needs to be up-to-date when the user starts typing, and shouldn't trigger a template re-render whenever a new possibility comes in.  I'm not sure if that would have happened with my solution, but it's good to make it clear that it doesn't.  Also, using the rendered callback is more elegant and meteoric than wrapping the function call in a Meteor.defer().  Cool solution!

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the discussion on this. In light of this, I guess I'll choose my own answer - feels a little weird, so thanks for the encouragement.

Comment: @rdickert - do you know if anything has changed in the way Meteor handles variables since you suggested this that would cause 'items' to be unavailable to the defer function?  I've got identical code running and that variable doesn't seem to be getting passed around as it was for you.

Comment: @IanWhalen - You're right, the code didn't work if used by itself. I had it in a larger app that didn't run into the problem, which is sensitive to when the template is rendered. I have updated the answer to make the original code work, but I now think that most people should use the new code at the end, which basically follows zorlak's lead. Hope this helps!

Comment: Any idea how you might combine this with using a template event keyup to set a Session variable used in the subscription, sent into the publication function, to limit the publication records?  I am messing around with the concept for a large collection that cannot be sent to the client but I want to use typeahead.  The typeahead is rerendering at this time as the publication changes.

Comment: Any significant reason not to use this.find('#typeahead').typeahead here?

Comment: @SteeveCannon On your first question: It seems to me that for a non-client-replicated dataset, you may want to use a Meteor method call that just returns the array for the autocomplete, rather than using `publish`.

Comment: @SteeveCannon On your second question, I'm pretty sure that you have to use jQuery, because the `typeahead` functionality is implemented as a jQuery plugin. `this.find` would just give you a DOM element which wouldn't have a `typeahead` method.

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to use `Items.find({},{name: 1}).fetch()`, which will return an array of items and is reactive, so it will re-run its enclosing function whenever the query results change, as long as it's called in a reactive context.

For the `Template.myForm.set_typeahead` helper, you might want to call that query inside the helper itself, store the result in a local variable, and then call `Meteor.defer` with a function that references that variable.  Otherwise I'm not sure that the query will be inside a reactive context when it's called.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This was an old question I'd forgotten about. It turns out I have an answer of my own now. Please comment if you have thoughts one way or the other on this.

Comment: It looks like your answer was really the best for most situations after all. If you are curious, check out my revised answer, particularly the caution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

[here](http://takidashi.com/ajax-like-autocomplete-for-meteor-bootstrap.html) is my quick solution for bootstrap typeahead

On client side:

```
Template.items.rendered = ->
  $("input#item").typeahead
    source: (query, process) ->
      subscription = Meteor.subscribe "autocompleteItems", query, ->
        process _(Items.find().fetch()).pluck("name")
      subscription.stop() # here may be a bit different logic,
      # such as keeping all opened subsriptions until autocomplete
      # will be successfully completed and so on
      items: 5
```

On server side:

```
Meteor.publish "autocompleteItems", (query) ->
  Items.find
    name: new RegExp(query, "i"),
      fields: { name: 1 },
      limit: 5
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

I actually ended up approaching the autocompletion problem completely differently, using client-side code instead of querying servers. I think this is superior because Meteor's data model allows for fast multi-rule searching with custom rendered lists.

> https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-autocomplete

Autocompleting users with `@`, where online users are shown in green:

[image]

In the same line, autocompleting something else with metadata and bootstrap icons:

[image]

Please fork, pull, and improve!

Comment: It's a solid attempt, but the lack of pub/sub with the autocomplete really hampers this (I also won't use it because of its dependancies, but that's a personal issue).

Comment: @JonathanDumaine As I mentioned in the README, this would be easy to extend to a server-side implementation. Also what dependencies? It only uses core Meteor.