# Can't get jQuery-ui autocomplete to work in Meteor

Tags: jquery-ui, meteor

I see that others are successfully using jQuery-ui within Meteor, but my first attempts to play with autocomplete have failed. Here's what I've tried:

I put the downloaded jquery-ui files in my client directory (I didn't keep the jQuery files as  jquery is already available). This fails because jQuery looks for the css files using a relative path, and Meteor doesn't serve them that way - it flattens the paths,  and when the original path is requested, it returns the main page of the app; Chrome dev tools returns an error indicating that it was expecting css but got text/html. You can get the autocomplete to drop down, but it closes as soon as you arrow-key or mouseover an option.

I then tried using a [jQuery-ui smart package from barisbalic on github](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/pull/48). This causes autocomplete to function almost normally once you add the css to the project. However, the dropdown `<ul>` appears in the upper-lefthand corner of the window instead of at its correct position under the `<input>` element.

What's the right way to do this? I've looked at Meteorite and Atmosphere and didn't find a package. Do I need to learn to build my own smart packages?

Answer (score 1):

Use your form's rendered event to start autocomplete.

You need to flatten your datasource or collection into an array (like addr_book, below), which can be done via a Meteor.autorun() on the collection:

```
function split( val ) {
  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
}

function extractLast( term ) {
  return split( term ).pop();
}


Template.compose_to_cc_bcc_subject.rendered = function () {
  start_compose_autocomplete();
}

function start_compose_autocomplete() {
  $("#field1 #field2").autocomplete({
      minLength: 0,
      source: function( request, response ) {
        response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
         addr_book, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
      },
      focus:function() {
        return false;
      },
      select: function( event, ui ) {
        var terms = split( this.value );
        // remove the current input
        terms.pop();
        // add the selected item
        terms.push( ui.item.value );
        // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
        terms.push( "" );
        this.value = terms.join( ", " );
        return false;
    }
  });
}
```

This uses the [jQuery autocomplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple), with multiple values.

Comment: This looks like good code, but my problem is more fundamental. I can get autocomplete to work on fields once loaded, but there is something wrong with how I'm loading it, and it doesn't function correctly. What I'm looking for is the best practice for loading outside libraries into Meteor when they don't have smart packages. I love `meteor add bootstrap`. Unfortunately, I can't yet do `meteor add jquery-ui`. How are you loading it?

Comment: We simply grabbed the jQuery-ui and put it into the ./public directory (and ultimately minified it). We made a couple of irrelevant tweaks. We didn't modify the autocomplete widget.

Comment: Well, that sounds easy. I thought I tried that, but maybe I missed something and am overcomplicating this. Thanks for the reply back - hopefully I'll be back to report success.